# Derivative of trigonometric function question

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Find the derivative of this function

$$\frac{1-\cos x}{\cos x - x \sin x -1}.$$

And the answer was

$$\frac{\sin x}{-\sin x- \sin x - x \cos x}.$$

But my answer was the same but with a positive sign before $ x \cos x$ and I don't know how he got the negative sign from.

Comment: You are presumably not differentiating the **function**, but the top and bottom, in order to use L'Hospital's Rule. The derivative of $x\sin x$ is $x\cos x+\sin x$. So the derivative of $-x\sin x$ is $-(x\cos x+\sin x)$, which is $-x\cos x-\sin x$.

Comment: agh got it thanks.

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/566224/trignometric-function-question

Comment: @AndréNicolas Please consider converting your comment into an answer, so that this question gets removed from the unanswered tab